# How to use app's sass variables in decorators of storybook (React)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader, storybook

I've built a website with Gatsby.js (static website generator with React) and am trying to add storybook to it.

I added a custom webpack config to storybook (following the instruction at https://storybook.js.org/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) to load sass and sass-resources, but can't make it work.

Followings are the configurations. I have installed all of the "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader", "sass-resources-loader" as well as "node-sass" for "storybook/react" in addition to those originally added to "gatsby" and "gatsby-plugin-sass" as dependencies.

It will be great if somebody kindly advise. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

**structure**

```
root - .storybook - addon.js
                  - config.js
                  - webpack.config.js
     - src        - components        - Component_1     - Component_1.js
                                                        - Component_1.scss
                                                        - Component_1.stories.js
                                      - ...
                  - styles            - _variables.scss
                                      - mixins          - _mixin_1.scs
                                                        - ...
                  - ...
    - ...
```

**webpack.config.js** (root/.storybook/webpack.config.js)

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-resources-loader",
            options: {
              resources: [
                "src/styles/_variables.scss",
                "src/styles/mixins/**/*.scss"
              ]
            },
          },
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**component_1.stories.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react";
import Component_1 from "./Component_1";

storiesOf("Component_1", module)
  .addDecorator(story => (
    <div style={{backgroundColor: $color-primary}}>
      {story()}
    </div>
))
  .add("default", () => (
    <Component_1>
      This is Component 1!
    </Component_1>
));
```

**error message** (shown on storybook app)

```
$color is not defined

ReferenceError: $grey is not defined
  at http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:80090:33
  at http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:57555:14
  at http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:57556:16
  at WrapStory.render(http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:61197:14)
  at http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44767:21
  at measureLifeCyclePerf (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44047:12)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44766:25)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44793:32)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44333:30)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44229:21)
```

In this case, sass variable "$color-primary" is defined in "src/styles/_variables.scss". I want to use it to style the Component_1 shown in the storybook app.

I tried importing "_variables.scss" expressly to "Component_1.stories.js" and failed again (Skiped "sass-resources-loader", just used "sass-loader").

Thank you for your advices.

[edit]

In addition to above, my storybook config file is as follow.

**config.js** (root/.storybook/config.js)

```
import { configure, addDecorator } from "@storybook/react";

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
const req = require.context('../src/components', true, /\.stories\.js$/);

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Comment: did you end up solving the problem? I was able to get it to work with the Gatsby v2 documentation + Storybook documentation for adding Sass to configs.

Answer (score -2):

There is a `:export` property for sharing variables. You can refer following link for sharing variables between sass and JavaScript.
https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass

Comment: Thank you. I did follow the instruction in above mentioned link and configured to load ".stories.js" files in each component directory. I don't think that the storybook config caused the sass variable loading problem.

Answer (score -4):

Try to add the path to your variables in the storybook config file

```
import "../src/styles/_variables.scss";
```

Comment: This does nothing but break Storybook with SyntaxError: Unexpected string